# KivyMD NavigationDrawer slides over multiple screens

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Using KivyMD MDNavigationLayout, I'm trying to make a navigation drawer for an app! I did it that way, however my navigation drawer now moves across several screens! I only want it to appear on my **HomeScreen**, not my **MenuScreen**!

Thank you so much for what you've done.

KV Code:

```
MDScreen: 
    MDNavigationLayout:
        ScreenManager:
            HomeScreen:
                id: home
                MDBoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    MDToolbar: 
                        title: 'Navigation Drawer'
                        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state('toggle')]]
                    Widget: 
            MenuScreen:
                id: menu
        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer            

<HomeScreen>:
    name: 'home_screen'
    MDLabel:
        id: label
        text: 'Home Screen'
        halign: 'center'  
    MDRaisedButton:
        text: 'Menu Screen'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.4}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu_screen'

<MenuScreen>:
    name: 'menu_screen'
    MDLabel:
        text: f'Menu Screen from Home Screen'
        halign: 'center'
    MDRaisedButton:
        text: 'Home Screen'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.4}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'home_screen'
```

**HomeScreen:**

[image: HomeScreen]

**MenuScreen:**

[image: MenuScreen]

Answer (score 2):

The NavigationDrawer is a widget that is designed to work across many screens. It will show up across multiple screens. If we take a closer look at you`.kv` file we can figure out why. Notice how the `MDNavigationLayout` is above your `Screenmanager`. This means that all the Screens that come under your ScreenManager(A widget that basically manages your screen and allows you to switch between them easily) will be shown in the NavigationLayout.

There isn't really a way to exclude a Screen from showing the NavigationDrawer as the widget was designed to show itself across all screens that are under it

As can be seen here in the docs examples:
[https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/0.104.1/components/navigation-drawer/[kivymd](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/0.104.1/components/navigation-drawer/%5Bkivymd) docs][1](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/0.104.1/components/navigation-drawer/)

Answer (score 2):

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout

KV = '''
<ContentNavigationDrawer>:

    ScrollView:

        MDList:

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Screen 1"
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "scr 1"

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Screen 2"
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "scr 2"


MDScreen:

    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        elevation: 10
        title: "MDNavigationDrawer"
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]

    MDNavigationLayout:
        x: toolbar.height

        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager

            MDScreen:
                name: "scr 1"

                MDLabel:
                    text: "Screen 1"
                    halign: "center"

            MDScreen:
                name: "scr 2"

                MDLabel:
                    text: "Screen 2"
                    halign: "center"

        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer

            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                screen_manager: screen_manager
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer
'''


class ContentNavigationDrawer(MDBoxLayout):
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()


class TestNavigationDrawer(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


TestNavigationDrawer().run()
```

https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/navigationdrawer/#switching-screens-in-the-screenmanager-and-using-the-common-mdtoolbar